# deleteActiveSheet not found in object Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want delete one sheet in my spreadsheet.

my code is:

```
  var go = workSheet.getSheetByName("Mail");

  go.deleteActiveSheet();
```

I receive an error message, and I don't understand what's wrong.

> deleteActiveSheet not found in object Sheet

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `deleteActiveSheet()` on the **Spreadsheet** ([see the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet)).

So your code should look something like this.

```
var sheet = worksheet.getSheetByName("Mail");
worksheet.setActiveSheet(sheet);
worksheet.deleteActiveSheet();
```